# Fast inner product of two 2-d masked arrays in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

My problem is the following. I have two arrays `X` and `Y` of shape n, p where **p >> n** (e.g. n = 50, p = 10000).

I also have a mask `mask` (1-d array of booleans of size `p`) with respect to `p`, of **small** density (e.g. `np.mean(mask)` is 0.05).

I try to compute, as fast as possible, the inner product of `X` and `Y` with respect to `mask`: the output `inner` is an array of shape `n, n`, and is such that `inner[i, j] = np.sum(X[i, np.logical_not(mask)] * Y[j, np.logical_not(mask)])`.

I have tried using the `numpy.ma` library, but it is quite slow for my use:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.ma as ma
n, p = 50, 10000
density = 0.05
mask = np.array(np.random.binomial(1, density, size=p), dtype=np.bool_)
mask_big = np.ones(n)[:, None] * mask[None, :]
X = np.random.randn(n, p)
Y = np.random.randn(n, p)
X_ma = ma.array(X, mask=mask_big)
Y_ma = ma.array(Y, mask=mask_big)
```

But then, on my machine, `X_ma.dot(Y_ma.T)` is about 5 times slower than `X.dot(Y.T)`...

To begin with, I think it is a problem that `.dot` does not know that the mask is only with respect to `p` but I don't if its possible to use this information.

I'm looking for a way to perform the computation without being much slower than the naive dot.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: For regular numeric arrays `np.dot` uses fast compiled BLAS (or similar) libraries.  I don't know the details of what it does with masked arrays,  At the very least it has to do an additional `dot` to handle the mask.  I know that in case of `object` dtype arrays it makes use of the * and + methods of the objects.

Comment: `scipy.sparse` might be the way to go here - you could convert your X and Y to sparse matrices, and go from there

Comment: In the demo, you are masking out only 5% of the terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `matrix-multiplication` with and without the masked versions as the masked subtraction from the full version yields to us the desired output -

```
inner = X.dot(Y.T)-X[:,mask].dot(Y[:,mask].T)
```

Or simply use the reversed mask, would be slower though for a sparsey `mask` -

```
inner = X[:,~mask].dot(Y[:,~mask].T)
```

Timings -

```
In [34]: np.random.seed(0)
    ...: p,n = 10000,50
    ...: X = np.random.rand(n,p)
    ...: Y = np.random.rand(n,p)
    ...: mask = np.random.rand(p)>0.95

In [35]: mask.mean()
Out[35]: 0.0507

In [36]: %timeit X.dot(Y.T)-X[:,mask].dot(Y[:,mask].T)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.54 ms per loop

In [37]: %timeit X[:,~mask].dot(Y[:,~mask].T)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.1 ms per loop

In [39]: %%timeit
    ...: inner = np.empty((n,n))
    ...: for i in range(X.shape[0]):
    ...:     for j in range(X.shape[0]):
    ...:         inner[i, j] = np.sum(X[i, ~mask] * Y[j, ~mask])
1 loop, best of 3: 302 ms per loop
```