# efficient masked dot product in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

If I have two vectors and a sparse mask with mostly 0's and a few 1's, is there an efficient way to compute the masked dot product of `a` and `b`? My solution is very inefficient because it computes a bunch of zeros that don't contribute to the result:

```py
a = np.random.normal(size=1000)
b = np.random.normal(size=1000)
m = np.random.choice([0,1], size=1000, p=[0.99, 0.01])

prod = np.sum(a*b*m)
```

(in my actual problem I have n-dim arrays rather than 1-dim, but the question is the same)

Comment: Have you looked at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54294577/fast-inner-product-of-two-2-d-masked-arrays-in-numpy

Comment: Trying to avoid those zeros might be more expensive than using them.  Be sure to time test suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

```
mask = np.where(m > 0)
np.sum(a[mask] * b[mask])
```

== UPDATE ==

As noted by commenters, writing the second line as
`a[mask].dot(b[mask])` is slightly faster. Presumably Numpy doesn't need to build the intermediate array.

Comment: shouldn't you use `np.sum` instead of `sum`

Comment: @Kenan For one-dimensional arrays, they both work, but yeah, you're right.

Comment: `a[mask].dot(b[mask]` is better.  Or `np.einsum('i,i,i', a,b,m)`.

Comment: I agree that `a[mask].dot(b[mask])` is a good alternative, but I was trying to stay as close to poster's original code.  I'm not so sure about `np.einsum`.  How is that in any way different from the `np.sum(a*b*m)` that poster was trying to avoid?  The whole point is that we only needed to do about 1% of the multiplies.

Comment: Also `mask` can just be `m.astype(bool)`

Comment: @DanielF.  Yeah.  It's not completely obvious to me which is faster or clearer.

Comment: Actually, after some testing with 100k values, `mask = np.where(m > 0)` is the fastest method I can find.  The summation is fastest with @hpaulj 's `a[mask].dot(b[mask])` though

Comment: [I knew I'd done this before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45764955/shuffling-non-zero-elements-of-each-row-in-an-array-python-numpy/45812861#45812861) - `mask = np.nonzero(m.astype(bool))` is a smidge faster, although not nearly as readable.

Comment: `einsum` is much slower than things like tensordot or dot though